# Excel Online Javascript Api Add Allow Edit Range

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, exceljs

I'm having trouble adding an allowed edit range to a worksheet protection object using Excel Javascript API. I keep getting an error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add'). I believe I've added the property with statement

```
worksheet.load("protection/protected", "protection/allowEditRanges");
```

but maybe this is wrong?

I've referred to the API reference here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.alloweditrangecollection?view=excel-js-preview

```
async function protect(worksheetName) {
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    worksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem(worksheetName);
    worksheet.load("protection/protected", "protection/allowEditRanges");
    await context.sync();
    //can't add without pausing protection 
    worksheet.protection.unprotect("");
           
    var wholerange = worksheet.getRange();
    wholerange.format.protection.locked = true;                            

    worksheet.protection.allowEditRange.add({title: "Range1", rangeAddress: "A4:G500"});
    worksheet.protection.allowEditRange.add({title: "Range2", rangeAddress: "I4::L500"});        

    worksheet.protection.protect({
        allowFormatCells: true,
        allowAutoFilter: true,
        allowDeleteRows: true,
        allowEditObjects: true,
        //allowFormatColumns: true,
        allowFormatRows: true,
        allowInsertHyperlinks: true,
        allowInsertRows: true,
        allowPivotTables: true,
        allowSort: true
    }, "");

    await context.sync();

});
```

}

##########UPDATE########
I've added this update because it's been suggested that this error is because of use of standalone O365 excel desktop app but this is not the case.
The error is happening on an Add-in for excel used in a tab through a browser. This is as online as I can understand..

Comment: Are you sure the load command shouldn't be changed to this:
    worksheet.load("protection/protected", "protection/allowEditRange"); (notice the omission of the last s)

Comment: i tried that as well but same error

Comment: The correct syntax for the load statement is     worksheet.load("protection/protected,protection/allowEditRanges");
and for the other two it is:     worksheet.protection.allowEditRanges.add("Range1", "A4:G500");
    worksheet.protection.allowEditRanges.add("Range2", "I4::L500");
Still, that gives an error: "RichApi.Error", code: "NotImplemented"

Comment: And of course the two : characters in the last statement in my previous comment need to be replaced with a single :

Comment: thanks for further info jk. The api reference isn’t a great help as there are very few actual code examples.

Comment: I agree, more samples would be very helpful

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the "NotImplementedError" is due to the AllowEditRangeCollection class-related API only supported on Excel Online. On my side, after modify to the right grammar as @jkpieterse suggests, the behavior on online is normal without any errors.
[image]

Comment: Good catch! This was a good read, I had no idea API's wouldn't work on Windows. And this doesn't seem like something that should be restricted to online.. So much for "cross platform".... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/excel/excel-api-online-requirement-set?view=common-js-preview

Comment: I would add this to your answer perhaps `if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("ExcelApiOnline", "1.1")) {`

Comment: im aware of this but I’m using Excel O365 & still get the non implemented error. So it is still an issue even with online version

Comment: You should see it work if you run your add-in in Excel on-line as opposed to in desktop Excel.

Comment: I am running my add-in Excel Online but still get the error. We only have the basic O365 subscription and excel is running in the browser not as stand alone app. The add-in is developed on visual studio.